# Android: problem in getText method of EditText

Tags: android, gettext, android-edittext

In my project I have two activities or classes. In first activity I have a EditText and I want to get the text of it from second class.

In the first class I wrote this code but it seems has problem.

```
public String getTextMessage()
{
    return textMessage.getText().toString();
}
```

because in second class when I want to get it, program crashes.

```
message = encode.getTextMessage();
```

What is your suggestion?

Comment: Send the logcat please. Also, are you sure you initialized `encode`?

Comment: Yes, that and is `textMessage` a class variable?

Comment: probably textMessage = null? did you do findViewById at the top? did you give the right id? yes, logcat please and more lines of code. like where is the other class, when is it called ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the text by getText() from edit text and store it in an string. when you move to second activity sent string variable to second class via bundel. Extract the bundel in second class and use it.

Comment: that is probably the way he needs to go.. but because of lack of information we are not really sure what he wants to do :D

Answer (score 2):

As told by sunil you have to firstly get string from edittextbox and through intent send it to another second activity. After start of second activity you have to get text from bundle.
code snippet is given below...

**Activity A**

```
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Second.class);
            i.putExtra("EXTRATEXT", editText.gettext().toString());
            startActivity(i);
```

**Activity B**

```
Class Second extends Activity{
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String text = getIntent().getExtras().getString("EXTRATEXT");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the value through intents